# Displayng javascript pop up from VB code

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

Using VS 2013 and asp.net VB.

I am using javascript to display a pop up to the user if some data is missing from a form they need to complete. The code is below

### Passing string to sub

```
Notification("alert('Please complete all fields in this section.')")
```

### The Sub

```
    Public Sub Notification(ByVal text As String)

    Dim script As String = text
    If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered(Me.GetType(), "alertscript") Then
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "alertscript", script, True)

    End If

End Sub
```

I get the following error

> JavaScript critical error at line 500, column 53 in http://localhost:61157/NewNCR.aspx\n\nSCRIPT1004: Expected ';'

The thing is I have used the same piece of code in a previous application and it works fine.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe you need to put a ";" after alert function?

Comment: Where would you suggest?  Also this code is identical to my other application (as I copied it) and that works.

Comment: Nope, that wasn't the issue, I tried and it worked without putting the comma after alert. Sorry. :/

Comment: I just created a new website and copied the code in, still doesnt work in my main application which is annoying

Comment: Sorry, no idea about the issue. :/